# How can I revert to the defaults in LyX?

Tags: fonts, lyx

New LyX user here. How can I restore LyX to its original document defaults?* (I have tried reinstalling LyX, but that didn't work.)

*I want to do this, because I want to return to the default fonts. Also, for some reason my PDF output isn't rendering (math symbols) properly and changes the font.

If there is is a better way to fix these (possibly related problems) let me know.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you need to delete a set of config files that is created by LyX. Reinstalling LyX does not, probably, delete those files and the new LyX install sees the old configs. Under Linux you can delete your `~/.lyx` directory, under Windows a similar directory under `Documents and settings` (the name of this folder heavily depends on which version of Windows you use, if any :).

Comment: I'm using a mac..I did try trashing the configs and preferences.

Comment: Is this only in lyx, or also in plain latex.